# Can the localStorage be cleared for a specific application?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Can the localStorage be cleared for a specific application?

The usecase is the following:
- we have a self built application called "Agent Cockpit" which is sharing the same domain name like Application1
- this agent cockpit uses local storage for some settings
- all these settings are lost when someone clicks "logout" on application1. We have noticed that when loging out of Application1 the command "LocalStorage.clear() is submitted which removes all items in the LocatStorage.

-- Using localstorage key with application identifier can I Prevent the above . However I Have the rights to make changes in the " Agent Cockpit " application only . Is there any documentation on how to achieve this? 
Or is it necessary to have a seperate key for all the applications using the localstorage ? Because making the changes in application1 is currently not possible.

How do i implement this?

Comment: `localStorage` is same-origin only, so you cannot modify other "applications" storage at all unless they are on the same domain

Comment: localStorage is domain-specific. So the second application will be affected only if it is on the same domain as the first

Comment: Be wary that browser extensions can also use local storage as if they are part of your domain. It pays to prefix your local storage names with an app identifier and then only remove those with the prefix, if you wish to be friendly to 3rd party browser extensions.

Comment: The usecase is the following:
- we have a self built application called "Agent Cockpit" which is sharing the same domain name like Application1
- this agent cockpit uses local storage for some settings
- all these settings are lost when someone klicks "logout" on application1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not **Native** functions available for this, Local Storage is set to a domain and is not for a specific application / virtual path.

With custom logics, i.e. prefix localstorage key with application identifier, and clear all the item with the prefix is possible

Comment: We have noticed that when loging out of Application1 the command "LocalStorage.clear() is submitted which removes all items in the LocatStorage.

-- Using localstorage key with application identifier can I Prevent the above . However I Have the rights to make changes in the " Agent Cockpit " application only . Is there any documentation on how to achieve this? Or is it necessary to have a seperate key for all the applications using the localstorage ? Because making the changes in application1 is currently not possible.

How do i implement this?

Comment: As I already said localStorage.clear() will **clear all the values** for that domain. So without editing the 'Application1', I hope !!, you can't achieve this !

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!! :) seems to be limitation with localstorage.

Comment: I hope that makes, this *answer* to be eligible to get accepted as a **Answer** !